# Execute curl command in gradle to upload files

Tags: gradle

I am trying to upload file using curl through gradle. I am facing some issues when executing build.gradle.

Code:

```
task publisher(dependsOn: rpmpackage)  {
    exec {
        executable "curl"; args "-k", "-u", "'un:pwd'" , " -F upload=@/distributions/test.rpm" , "http://ip:port/#browse/browse:test-files:com%2Fcompany%2Fcomponent"
    }
}
```

Error:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ; Unknown error

100  5037  100  5037    0     0  1703k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 1703k

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Nexus Repository Manager</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <meta name="description" content="Nexus Repository Manager"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>


  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script>(new Image).src="http://ip:port/static/rapture/resources/favicon.ico?_v=3.12.1-01"</script>
  <![endif]-->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://ip:port/static/rapture/resources/favicon-32x32.png?_v=3.12.1-01" sizes="32x32">
  ........................................

<form id="history-form" class="x-hide-display">
  <input type="hidden" id="x-history-field"/>
  <iframe id="x-history-frame"></iframe>
</form>

</body>
</html>

> Task :rpmpackage
> Task :publisher

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

File is not uploaded to the required location even if the build is successful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The quoting of username and password does not look correct. Try `"un:pwd"`.

Answer (score 3):

I got an solution for the above gradle issue.

this worked fine for me.

```
task publisher(dependsOn: rpmpackage)  {
    exec {
       executable "curl"; args "-k", "-v","-u",  "un:pwd" ,"-T", "$project.buildDir/distributions/test.rpm" , "http://ip:port/#browse/browse:test-files:com%2Fcompany%2Fcomponent"
}
}
```